# Pygame is not defined?

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting this error every time I run my code:

```
NameError: name 'pygame' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *

class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window ):
        window.geometry('320x100'); window.title('MNote Player'); window.resizable(0,0)
        Load = Button(window, text = 'Load',  width = 10, font = ('Lucida Grande', 14), command = self.load)
        Play = Button(window, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Lucida Grande', 14), command = self.play)
        Pause = Button(window,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Lucida Grande', 14), command = self.pause)
        Stop = Button(window ,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Lucida Grande', 14), command = self.stop)
        Load.place(x=0,y=20);Play.place(x=110,y=20);Pause.place(x=220,y=20);Stop.place(x=110,y=60) 
        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False
    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state=True
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
    def stop(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
root = Tk()
app= MusicPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have no other `.py` file called `pygame`, and I have checked many similar problems, and I cannot find an answer.. I am only a beginner, so please don't go to harsh on me!

Comment: Just remove all the `pygame` from the code like make `pygame.mixer.init()` to `mixer.init()`, this is because, your importing `mixer` directly and dont have to suffix it with `pygame` or just change your import statement to `import pygame.mixer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not importing `pygame`. You *are*, however, importing `pygame.mixer`. So use that directly in your code (`mixer.init()` etc. instead of `pygame.mixer.init()`).

Alternatively, change the import directive from

```
from pygame import mixer
```

to

```
import pygame.mixer
```

Comment: An alternative might be to change the import statement to do `import pygame.mixer` instead of `from pygame import mixer`.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, I agree that’s better.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import pygame
```

then run the code.

Answer (score 0):

you do not actually import `pygame` please add `import pygame` to use the whole module. When you use `from pygame import mixer` and `from pygame.locals import *` you are importing submodules if they have a `__init__` inside or just plain classes or files if they do not include `__init__`.

Importing pygame by itself imports the pygame module so that you can call it and activate that `__init__` or call submodules.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I explained why it did not work the other answer only tells you what to do which is not very helpful in the sense that the user doesn't understand why it does not work

Comment: @Rabbid76 so when I stated " you did not actually import `pygame`" that doesn't tell the user why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 is that better?